# What does it mean for a matrix $A$ to have only real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so I'm reading Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* and at one point he mentions that the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has imaginary eigenvalues and it also is a matrix that rotates. And in general imaginary numbers are associated with rotation so what I'm wondering is: do exclusive real eigenvalues correspond to just the act of stretching, imaginary eigenvalues to just the act of rotating and lastly complex eigenvalues, provided both that $\operatorname{Im}(\lambda_i) \neq 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda_i)\neq 0$ correspond to both stretching and rotating.

EDIT: My question is referring to square matrices and their eigenvalues exclusively. Not any kind of matrices.
(Also, by $\lambda_i$ I mean every eigenvalue of those hypothetical matrices.)

Comment: Not quite: the eigenvalues are imaginary specifically because it rotates by an angle of $\pi/2$.

Comment: Please specify whether your question is about 2 by 2 matrices only, or any square matrix.

Comment: A very basic way of getting some intuition behind this is considering the special case of a $1\times 1$ matrix, which is just a complex number $\lambda$. If $\lambda = R \in\mathbb{R}$ is real, then it multiplies the amplitude of each number on the complex plane by $R$. If $\lambda = e^{i\phi}$ (which is only imaginary for $\phi = \pm \pi/2 + 2k\pi$), then it rotates every number on the complex plane by angle $\phi$. Finally, if $\lambda=Re^{i\phi}$, then it does both stretching and rotation simultaneously. In the higher dimensional case, look at each eigenvalue seperately to see what it does.

Comment: The [3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g) on eigenvalues and eigenvectors is really useful for gaining intuition on this topic.

Comment: @eyeballfrog this is what I'm literally asking...I'm asking whether if a matrix only rotates it follows that said matrix will have only imaginary eigenvalues. Please re-read my question.